# Get the unread mail count gmail

Tags: android

Gmail.java link as referred to in one of the questions on SO is broken.

My code is

```
String account="abc.xyz@gmail.com";
      Uri LABELS_URI = Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/unread/");
      Log.d("pavan","label "+LABELS_URI );
      Uri ACCOUNT_URI = Uri.withAppendedPath(LABELS_URI, account);
      Log.d("pavan","label "+ACCOUNT_URI );
      ContentResolver contentResolver= this.getContentResolver();
      Log.d("pavan","contentResolver "+contentResolver );
      Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ACCOUNT_URI, null, null, null, null);
```

but the contentResolver line is throwing an error, the logcat says:
cannot find provider info for gmail-ls.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Android Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/android/), if it meets your needs. Otherwise, the Gmail application [no longer supports access](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/08/gmail-gone-risk-undocumented-apis.html) such as what you are doing.